# sending a http request in webPage but prevent opening the page

Tags: javascript, php, html, http, web

there is a sms service that can send sms only with a http request.
like this: http://domain/SendMessage.ashx?user=[user]&pass=[pass]&lineNo=[lineNo]&to=[to]&text=[text]

if i open this webPage in my webSite , the user can see the user and pass. i want to send this http request but in background (the user should not see the address) and no new tab opened , nothing changes but in background this http request become sent.

UPDATE:

i have this code in another file (sendSms.php):

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<?php

$userName=$_POST ['userName'];
$password=$_POST ['password'];
$lineNumber=$_POST ['lineNumber'];
$to=$_POST ['Receiver'];
$text=$_POST ['messageBody'];

date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Tehran');
$client= new SoapClient('http://n.sms.ir/ws/SendReceive.asmx?wsdl');

$parameters['userName'] = $userName;
$parameters['password'] = $password;
$parameters['mobileNos'] = array(doubleval($to));
$parameters['messages'] = array($text);
$parameters['lineNumber'] = $lineNumber;
$parameters['sendDateTime'] = date("Y-m-d")."T".date("H:i:s");
print_r($client->SendMessageWithLineNumber($parameters));
?>
```

what i don't know is how to use it in java script , i also got the receiver's phone number in first page by this code:

```
jQuery("#iva_apt_phone").val();
```

Comment: Can't you use a POST request? With AJAX.... what are you actually doing this for?

Comment: Use AJAX which does everything in background

Comment: When the user wants to send a sms you can first POST the data to your server, caputure that POST data and then use curl to send it to the sms service.

Answer (score 0):

try initiating a curl request from server. when the user initiate send sms, you can make a ajax request to the server without mentioning sensitive information.

then in the server make curl request. like,

```
$curl = curl_init('http://domain/SendMessage.ashx?user=[user]&pass=[pass]&lineNo=[lineNo]&to=[to]&text=[text]');
$result = curl_exec($curl);
```

for detailed information on requests using curl,
http://codular.com/curl-with-php

Comment: thanks , would you please check the update of my question ?